# Como fazer uma multipart post request com RestClient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como fazer uma multipart post request com a biblioteca RestClient? Basicamente, preciso

a) salvar fotos postadas por meio de um formulário em um diretório local.
b) ter acesso ao metadados como nome do arquivo, tamanho...

Como meus conhecimentos em ruby ainda são muito limitados, mesmo lendo a documentação eu ainda não consigo. Já vi que a rest-client é uma boa opção para o caso. O que entendi até agora é que tenho que proceder mais ou menos assim:

Importar a biblioteca:

```
require rest-client
```

Criar uma classe contendo um código mais ou menos assim:

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post, url: "http://localhost:8080/upload", 
  timeout: 600, 
  payload: {
    multipart: true,
    file: File.new('/root/tmp/images, 'rb')
    }
  )
```

Supondo que o código acima esteja correto (sugestões?), como posso acessar o metadados?

Comment: Queres acessar o metadados do lado que recebe a requisição ou o lado que faz a requisição?

Comment: Do lado que recebe. Alguma idéia?

Comment: Você deve primeiro debugar a ação do controller que está recebendo essa requisição, então, você verifica se você está recebendo a imagem lá, você pode fazer isso vendo o que está nos seus params. Depois disso, você pode tentar carregar a imagem e ver se tem todas as informações que você tem, vai na documentação da class File em Ruby e vê como obter informações. Você também pode olhar a gem mini_magick, é boa para acessar essas informações.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou pesquisar por esses termos que vc citou.